# My secret password in oracle won't output

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to output my procedure, with a secret password. When i try to run my code it doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR replace Procedure hiddenPasswords(
       p_MA_ID IN MitarbeiterAccounts.MitarbetierAccountID%TYPE,
       p_M_Login IN MitarbeiterAccounts.Mitarbeiter_Login%TYPE,
       p_M_Password IN MitarbeiterAccounts.Mitarbeiter_Password%TYPE)


IS
BEGIN

        INSERT INTO MitarbeiterAccounts(MitarbeiterAccountsID, 
         MitarbeiterAccounts_Login, Mitarbeiter_Password)
        VALUES(p_MA_ID, p_M_Login, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', p_M_Password));

END;
/

EXEC hiddenPasswords p_MA_ID = 4, p_M_Login = 'Admin' p_M_Password = N'123';
```

I'm getting that HASHBYTES is invalid identifier

Comment: Well, then obviously your database does not know about that function - what makes you think that it should be there?

Comment: I was thinking this is supposed be a built one in oracle

Comment: [Built-in functions are in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Functions.html). It's possible you have a bespoke function from another schema that you are able to call from SQL or an anonymous block, but not from a procedure, but it's more likely that it doesn't exist at all, and you're thinking of the [T-SQL function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). [This might be useful](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/manually-encrypting-data.html).

Comment: Look at the answer by @ArunPalanisamy below.  Extra comment: when you get this working in Oracle, you should also generate a random "salt" value, insert it (unencrypted) into a separate column in your `MitarbeiterAccounts` table and also append it to your `p_M_Password` in your hash function.  E.g., `dbms_crypto.hash(p_m_password || l_salt_value), 6 /* 6 => SHA-2, 512 bit */)`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Oracle doesn't have any built-in function called `HASHBYTES`. It is there in **SQL SERVER** but not in **Oracle**

instead you can use `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH` if you have that privilege for the same.

> DBMS_CRYPTO provides an interface to encrypt and decrypt stored data, and can be used in conjunction with PL/SQL programs running network communications

[**DBMS_CRYPTO**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS664)

**Update**

For eg., I have used `RAW` here. You can check other `Overloaded functions` in the above link where you can use `BLOB`, `CLOB` as well.

```
DECLARE
 l_pwd VARCHAR2(19) := 'mysecretpassword';
 l_ccn_raw RAW(128) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_pwd);
 l_encrypted_raw RAW(2048);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('CC:  ' || l_ccn_raw);

  l_encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.hash(l_ccn_raw, 1);
  dbms_output.put_line('MD4: ' || l_encrypted_raw);

  l_encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.hash(l_ccn_raw, 2);
  dbms_output.put_line('MD5: ' || l_encrypted_raw);

  l_encrypted_raw := dbms_crypto.hash(l_ccn_raw, 3);
  dbms_output.put_line('SH1: ' || l_encrypted_raw);
END;
/
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CC:  6D7973656372657470617373776F7264
MD4: BBBA2CBC2F6E0F158D06B34F819DB5F6
MD5: 4CAB2A2DB6A3C31B01D804DEF28276E6
SH1: 08CD923367890009657EAB812753379BDB321EEB
```

Comment: This answer would maybe be improved with an example based on the OP's code.  E.g., `dbms_crypto(p_m_password,dbms_crypto.hash_sh512)` or `dbms_crypto.hash(p_m_password), 6 /* 6 => SHA-2, 512 bit */)`.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak  added few examples now :)